# white space when adding float: none to image

Tags: html, css

I have been optimizing a website i've been working on for mobile phones using strategies from Ethan Marcotte's Responsive web design book, and in adding float:none !important; I cleared a previous float, but there is extra white space to the right of the website, and causes unnecessary scroll. I've tried applying overflow-x:hidden to both the #image div and to html, body,  - but it doesn't seem to work. I've also tried to find ghost elements using http://wernull.com/2013/04/debug-ghost-css-elements-causing-unwanted-scrolling/ , but that didn't lead me anywhere either. If someone could help me with this that would be great, thank you!

website: cristinalord.com

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Cristina Lord</title>
    <link href="css/styles.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="site_title1">
                Cristina Lord
            </div>
            <div id="site_title2">
                Composer, Pianist
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li class="selected"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="images">
                <img src="images/cristina.png" alt="Cristina Lord">
            </div>  
            <div id="about">
                <p>Cristina is currently a senior at the University of California, Santa Barbara, where she is completing her B.A. degree in Music Composition at the College of Creative Studies. She will be pursuing her masters at Cal State Long Beach in the fall. While at UCSB, she has studied composition under William Kraft, Dr. Leslie Hogan, and Dr. Jeremy Haladyna, piano with Dr. Charles Asche, and conducting with Christopher Rountree.</p>
                <br>    
                <p>Cristina has worked as a piano teacher for the Santa Barbara School of Music for the past three years. She also regularly sings for the English Broadside Ballad Archive at UCSB, and is a member of the contemporary choral ensemble New Century Voices.</p>
                <br>    
                <p>Last year (2013), Cristina won a Corwin Award in the vocal category for her song cycle, Songs of American Women, which will be performed this year by the Ensemble for Contemporary Music and at the Primavera Festival at UCSB.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <footer>
                <p>Copyright Cristina Lord 2014 &copy;</p>
                <a href="http://www.facebook.com/cristina.lord"><img src="images/facebooklogo.png" height="40" width="40" alt="Facebook"></a>
                <a href="http://www.soundcloud.com/cristina_lord"><img src="images/soundcloudlogo.png" height="40" width="76" alt="SoundCloud"></a>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>


</html>
```

CSS:relevant css is:

```
/* media queries for different sizes */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    #images{
        min-width: 100%;
        float: none !important;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #about{
        text-align: center;
    }   
}
```

all of the css:

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/*CUSTOM FONTS*/

@font-face{
    font-family: 'OpenSans';
    src: url('../fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: bolder;
}

@font-face{
    font-family: 'OpenSans';
    src: url('../fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
}


@font-face{
    font-family: 'OpenSans';
    src: url('../fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
}



/* main font style, background color, and body paddings */


body{
    background-color: rgb(255,255,240);
    color:black;
    font-family: 'OpenSans';
    padding: 03.515625% 7.8125% 0% 7.8125%; /* 45, 100, 0, 100 / 1280px */
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.25em;

}

/* main header style */

div#site_title1 
{
    color:rgb(188,143,143);
    font-size: 1.75em; /* 28px / 16px */
    padding-bottom: 0.35714285714286em; /* 10 / 28px */
    font-family: 'OpenSans';
    font-weight: bolder;
    letter-spacing: 0.07142857142857em; /* 2 / 28px */
}

div#site_title2
{
    color:rgb(188,143,143);
    font-size: 1.25em; /* 20px / 16px */
    padding-bottom: 0.25em; /* 5 / 20px */
    font-family: 'OpenSans';
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em; /* 2 / 20px */

}

/*menu style*/

div#menu ul a
{
    font-size: 1.125em; /* 18 / 16px */
    padding-bottom: 0.55555555555556em; /* 10 / 18px */
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color 0.5s ease;
    border-color: rgb(255,255,240);

}

div#menu li
{   display: inline;}

div#menu ul a:hover
{
    color:rgb(188,143,143);
    border-bottom: 0.11111111111111em solid #BC8F8F; /* 2 / 18px */
    transition: border-color 0.5s ease;

}

div#menu
{word-spacing:0.27777777777778em; /* 5 / 18px */
text-align: center;}

#menu, #menu a {
    padding:0.55555555555556em 0.55555555555556em 1.11111111111111em 0.55555555555556em; /* 10 20 10 10 / 18px */
    margin-bottom: 0.55555555555556em; /* 10 / 18px */
}

div#menu li.selected a { color:rgb(188,143,143);border-bottom: 0.11111111111111em solid #BC8F8F;} 


/* about and image positioning */

div#about
{
    max-width: 49.074074074074%; /* 530 / 1080px */
    font-size: 1em;
      -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
       -moz-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Firefox */
        -ms-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Opera */
            animation: fadein 0.5s;
    line-height: 140%;
    }

div#images
{
    float:right;
    padding-right: 7.8125%;
    padding-left: 1.388888888889%; /* 15 / 1080px */
    padding-bottom: 1.388888888889%; /* 15 / 1080px */

    -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
       -moz-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Firefox */
        -ms-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Opera */
            animation: fadein 0.5s;
    width: 42.87037037037%; /* 463 */
    height:28.703703703704%; /* 310 */
    overflow: hidden;
}


/* event headers and text */
div#header{
    text-align: center;
}
.eventheader
{
    color:rgb(188,143,143);
    font-size: 1.125em; /* 18 / 16px */
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;

}

.eventsubheader
{
    color:#000;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;

}

.eventtext
{
    width: 37.037037037037%; /* 400 / 1080px */
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    position: center;
    text-align: center;
}


/* horizontal images - to be implemented */

#horizontalimage{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%; /* 1080 / 1080px */
    height:50%; /* 400 / 800px */ 
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1em black;

}

#horizontalimage img {
    display: block; /*removes inline element space for text */
}

span {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: "OpenSans" ;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.75em; /* 28 / 16px */
    color: rgb(188,143,143);
    bottom: 40%;
    text-align: left;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    padding-left: 10% !important; /* important overrides padding 2.5 for left */
    padding:2.5%; /* 10 / 1080px */
}

/* table positioning/style */

th{
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    width: 250px;
}

td{
    padding:1%;
    width: 250px;
}

div#tablelist{
    color:#000;
    font-size: 0.875em; /* 14 / 16px */
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#tablelist, #tablelist a {
padding-left:1.42857142857143em;
padding-right: 1.42857142857143em;
padding-bottom: 1.42857142857143em;
}

table {
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}


/* footer style */


html,
body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}

#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#content {
    padding-bottom:80px; /* 10 px added for extra padding between text and footer */
    overflow: auto;
}
#footer {

    border-top: 2px solid rgb(188,143,143);
    bottom:0;
    height:70px;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
    font-size: 0.75em; /* 12 / 16px */
}

body {
          box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    }


/* MISC. */

a:hover {color:rgb(188,143,143);}


.line{
    width:38%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}


a{text-decoration: none;
    color:#000;
        transition: color 0.5s ease;

    }
div#musicheader
{
    color:rgb(188,143,143);
    font-size: 1.25em; /* 20 / 16px */
    padding-bottom: 0.25em; /* 5 / 20px */
    font-family: 'OpenSans';
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em; /* 2 / 20px */

}

.issuuembed{
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#floatleft{
    float:left;
}

.floatleftmulti{
    float:left;
}

#floatright{
    float: right;
}

/* media queries for different sizes */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    #images{
        min-width: 100%;
        float: none !important;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #about{
        text-align: center;
    }   
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){

    #about{
        min-width: 100%;
    }
}


/*fadein and center*/


div#contenttext{
    -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
       -moz-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Firefox */
        -ms-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Opera */
            animation: fadein 0.5s;
            text-align: center;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
}

div#musiccontent{
    -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
       -moz-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Firefox */
        -ms-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Opera */
            animation: fadein 0.5s;

            text-align: center;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
}

.eventcontent{
    -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
       -moz-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Firefox */
        -ms-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Opera */
            animation: fadein 0.5s;
}

/* Firefox */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Safari and Chrome */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}​

/* Opera */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}​
```

Comment: Have you tried using the browser dev tools (inspector, firebug, etc.) to find the element that causes the increased width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `paddings to 0`:

```
/* media queries for different sizes */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
   #images{
      min-width: 100%;
      float: none !important;
      padding: 0 !important; /* <-----add this to see */
      text-align: center;
   }
   #about{
      text-align: center;
   }   
}
```

---

Also this could also cause the issue that you have applied the paddings to the `body` itself you can avoid this too:

```
/* media queries for different sizes */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
   body{
      padding:0 !important; /* <-----add this to see */
   }
   #images{
      min-width: 100%;
      float: none !important;
      padding: 0 !important; /* <-----add this to see */
      text-align: center;
   }
   #about{
      text-align: center;
   }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask why the !important tag is necessary? I thought that by putting it in the media query it would override the default css.

Answer (score 0):

The space is caused by paddings:

```css
div#images {
    padding-left: 1.38889%;
    padding-right: 7.8125%;
}
```

You can remove them, or use `box-sizing: border-box`.